# XMLHttpRequest in IE-7

Tags: javascript, xml, internet-explorer-7, xmlhttprequest

I'm creating XMLHttpRequest as follows:

```
function checkDependencyFormFilledStatus(appName,formName){
    var xmlhttp;
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("GET","checkFormDependency.action formName="+formName+"&applicationName="+appName,false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    var dependentFormEmptyStatus = Ext.JSON.decode(xmlhttp.responseText);
    alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
    return dependentFormEmptyStatus;
}
```

The response returned by the object is dependent on the database which the action class is using.

This works fine in Firefox 10.0.

But for IE7, it returns correct response only for the first time. And for the rest of the function calls, it returns the same response (no matter what changes we make in the database). It updates its response only when I close the tab and open it (not even on reloading the page).

How to make it work in IE 7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like the response is being cached.

Add a psuedo-random string (e.g. a timestamp) to the end of the URI to cache burst.

Comment: It worked.. Thank you... I converted the open call to xmlhttp.open("GET","checkFormDependency.action?formName="+formName+"&applicationName="+appName+"&timeStamp="+new Date().getTime(),false);

Answer (score 3):

you are simply having a caching issue with IE7, as it caches the XMLHttpRequest() after it  created it and store it in its memory.  even with subsequents `xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();` the variable don't get any assigment because **it already has an instance** (from your first `xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();` ) .

what you need to do is to *invalidate* and *destroy* your XMLHttpRequest request after every use.

you first create your XMLHttpRequest (for msie 7) like this:

```
function createXMLHttpRequest(){
    var xmlHttp = null;
    if(typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined"){
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if(typeof window.ActiveXObject != "undefined"){
        try {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.4.0");
        }
        catch(e){
            try {
                xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch(e){
                try {
                    xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                catch(e){
                    xmlHttp = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return xmlHttp;
}
```

so to create it each time in the function you want to use.

```
function checkDependencyFormFilledStatus(appName,formName){
    if(xmlHttp_global){
        xmlHttp_global.abort(); // abort the current request if there's one 
    }
    // Create the object each time a call is about to be made
    xmlHttp_global = createXMLHttpRequest();
    if(xmlHttp_global){
    xmlHttp_global.onreadystatechange = myCallbackFunction; // make you callback thing here
    xmlHttp_global.open("GET","checkFormDependency.action formName="+formName+"&applicationName="+appName,false);
    xmlHttp_global.send(null);
    }
}
```

in your callback ("onreadystatechange" function) you **delete** it after using it

```
function myCallbackFunction()
{
 if(xmlHttp_global && xmlHttp_global.readyState == 4){
 //do your thing here and ... or nothing 

var dependentFormEmptyStatus = Ext.JSON.decode(xmlhttp.responseText);
    alert(xmlhttp.responseText); // like this for example?

  xmlHttp_global = null; //delete your XMLHTTPRequest
 }

}
```

so IE 7 will find each time an empty reference and will have the need to recreate it again for each use.

if you don't want to create and delete it eacht time you simply play with some HTTP-Headers in your XMLHTTPRequest

```
xmlHttp_global.setRequestHeader("If-Modified-Since", "Thu, 1 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT");
xmlHttp_global.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
```

like suggested [here](http://ajaxian.com/archives/ajax-ie-caching-issue)

Another alternatives include:

- Using POST method over GET method

  xmlHttp_global.open("POST","checkFormDependency.action",false);
      xmlHttp_global.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); // or another content type , its up to you
      xmlHttp_global.send("formName="+formName+"&applicationName="+appName);
- Using a "dummy" variable in your query-String to burst out the cacher of IE(7,6)

  xmlHttp_global.open("GET","checkFormDependency.action formName="+formName+"&applicationName="+appName+"randomVar="+Math.Random(),false);

Links

- [XMLHTTPRequest cache in IE 7 and 6](http://robertnyman.com/2007/04/04/weird-xmlhttprequest-error-in-ie-just-one-call-allowed/)

Comment: I've created my variable locally. But you have written the code for global XMLHttpRequest variable. Is it necessary to make it global? I also tried to use abort() but it didn't work. I tried xmlhttp = null at the end too but I don't think it makes any sense as it is a local variable.

Comment: look you have 2 variables a local var xmlHttp in creation function and a global xmlHttp_global that receives the outcome of your create function. you can play with both of them at your convenience. the xmlHttp_global = null must be set after you used it in your callback and not anywhere  or anyhow... and if you  still have some problems with it, just try the alternative proposed after (e.g with request Headers) in my update